# Can't retrieve values for a specific child with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase and I want to only retrieve childs with a specific value (`activiteId`) for a given key (`"associationId"`)

What I tried:

```
firebase.database().ref().child("collectivites").child(collectiviteId).child("evenements").orderByChild("associationId").equalTo(activiteId).once("value", function (snapshotAssociationEvenements) {
  const data = snapshotAssociationEvenements.val();
  if (data){
   console.log(data);
  }
});
```

The problem :
The child is displayed in the console but if I do `console.log(snapshotAssociationEvenements.val().associationId);` the console returns undefined

What have I done wrong ?

My db
[image]

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
firebase.database().ref().child("collectivites").child(collectiviteId).child("evenements").orderByChild("associationId").equalTo(activiteId).once("value", function (snapshotAssociationEvenements) {
snapshotAssociationEvenements.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
   var associateId=childSnapshot.val().associationId;
});
```

Your snapshot is at the child `evenements`, then you loop inside the random id using the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and you will be able to access the children under that id.